# Комбинация модулей "tkinter" и "pytelegrambotapi"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, telebot

Хочу написать телеграмм бота на модуле в python "*pytelegrambotapi*".
Также решил использовать модуль "*tkinter*" для вывода на экран сообщений присланных telegram боту.

Ну вот в чём проблема:
Для роботы окна в модуле "*tkinter*" в конце кода нужна следующая строчка в конце кода:

```py
[Название окна].mainloop()
```

И совершенно то же требует модуль "*pytelegrambotapi*":

```py
[Имя бота].polling(none_stop=True)
```

И если я указываю например "*[Имя бота].polling(none_stop=True)*", то работает только бот. А если наоборот указываю первым "[Название окна].mainloop()", то работает только tkinter.

Код файла "test.py":

[image: Исходный код файла]

Текстовый код самого файла "*test.py*": https://pastebin.com/59RneB55

Comment: Потому что оба работают в одном потоке -- главном и оба используют циклы для обработки событий, поэтому используйте модуль `threading` и запустите бота в отдельном потоке, а tkinter оставьте в главном

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте модуль `threading`:

```
from threading import Thread
# Ваш код
todo=[]

todo.append(Thread(target=[Название окна].mainloop)) # добавляем поток tkinter
todo.append(Thread(target=[Имя бота].polling, kwargs={'none_stop'=True})) # добавляем поток bot
# запускаем потоки
for th in todo: th.start()
for th in todo: th.join()
```